# Use string variable in geb selectors

Tags: selenium, grails, groovy, spock, geb

I am testing my aplicaction using geb and spock frameworks. I have to check some dynamic fields that I generate their ID using DB info.

```
then:
String fieldID= "ID_34534_row"
assert $('\\#${fieldID}').displayed
```

this expression $('\#${fieldID}') is invalid

```
invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Could someone help me to find the correct selector expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be

```
assert $("#${fieldID}").displayed
```

Shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, It works. I have to use inverted commas (") instead of simple commas ('). Thank you

Comment: Another option would be to use: `assert $(id: fieldID).displayed` which will result in the exact same WebDriver commands being sent to the browser yet is more readable IMHO.